# Man Exists in earth

Tags: bible, history, science

According to Bible,

Man exists on earth before 7000 years Ago. But science has got too much improvements recently in all kind of area.Did the science can prove that there was existence of human before 7000 years. with whole proof???

If yes How Bible can explain that

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Bible Literalists deal with trees older than the flood?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15394/how-do-bible-literalists-deal-with-trees-older-than-the-flood)

Comment: Users must be very careful while answering this type of opinion based question. They must keep in mind that everyone have different opinions.

Comment: @Mawia: People shouldn't be answering opinion-based questions here. They should be voting to close such questions.

Comment: Relativity. Einstein and all that. 24 hours in one place millions of years in another.  Bible confirms science. Science comfirms Bible. No more argument. All peace.

Answer (score 5):

The Catholic Church accepts the [scientific understanding](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theistic_evolution) that our planet is older than 7,000 years.

Could an omnipotent God create the world according to our 24 hours, 7 days a week, 365 days a year, Gregorian measured snipets of time? Yes, absolutely!

[Did he choose to do it that way?](http://www.catholic.com/tracts/adam-eve-and-evolution) No.

It is ultimately necessary for Catholics and/or like minded Christians, who trust Sacred Scripture to keep in mind that:

1. The Bible is a collection of different types of literature...none of which are to be considered 100% scientific.
2. The Bible is not given to humanity to explain *how* the universe came into existence, but *why*.

Pope Pius XII warned us,

> "What is the literal sense of a passage is not always as obvious in the 
>    speeches and writings of the ancient authors of the East, as it is in the 
>    works of our own time. For what they wished to express is not to be 
>    determined by the rules of grammar and philology alone, nor solely by 
>    the context; the interpreter must, as it were, go back wholly in spirit to 
>    those remote centuries of the East and with the aid of history, 
>    archaeology, ethnology, and other sciences, accurately determine what 
>    modes of writing, so to speak, the authors of that ancient period would 
>    be likely to use, and in fact did use. For the ancient peoples of the East, in 
>    order to express their ideas, did not always employ those forms or kinds 
>    of speech which we use today; but rather those used by the men of their 
>    times and countries. What those exactly were the commentator cannot 
>    determine as it were in advance, but only after a careful examination of 
>    the ancient literature of the East" (Divino Afflante Spiritu 35–36).

It *should be stated* that although ["Theistic evolutionism" is the official position of the Catholic church](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholic_Church_and_evolution), Catholics are technically *not* obligated or required to hold this idea.

Concerning the doctrine on creation, Ludwig Ott in his *Fundamentals of Catholic Dogma* identifies the following points as essential beliefs of the Catholic faith ("De Fide"):

- All that exists outside God was, in its whole substance, produced out of nothing by God.
- God was moved by His Goodness to create the world.
- The world was created for the Glorification of God.
- The Three Divine Persons are one single, common Principle of the Creation.
- God created the world free from exterior compulsion and inner necessity.
- God has created a good world.
- The world had a beginning in time.
- God alone created the world.
- God keeps all created things in existence.
- God, through His Providence, protects and guides all that He has created.

The Catholic Church makes it clear that salvation is not determined by knowledge, but by love. The bottom line is that the created world was made to **glorify *God***.

Comment: -1's how about some feedback?

Comment: Will those downvoting please remember that you should not be downvoting based on your personal opinions. This answer represents the majority of Christianity. Even if you personally disagree with it, it is a good answer.

Comment: I haven't downvoted *yet*, but the claims you make about what "Scripture" is are highly debatable.  If you were to say who holds the scriptures as you do (namely Catholics and liberals), then this is an okay answer - but as it stands, you are claiming that all Christians believe this - and they just don't

Comment: I downvoted it because of the first line _"It is an absolute... "_. I can still change my mind :)

Comment: @Affable Geek  see my edit...

Comment: @Mawia see my edit

Comment: This is a much better answer :)  And I definitely haven't downvoted now.  Ultimately, I still think is a bad question. It's looking for a "You Christians are stoopid" response, to which your answer now correctly states "At least for Catholics, you're attacking a position that we don't hold."  Better answer to a question that ultimately probably isn't worthy of it.  I'll probably +1

Comment: Sorry, the down-vote with no comment was me.  It wasn't down-voted for content, but rather for even answering a question that should be closed outright.  Opinion-based questions are off-topic and always have been, and this one has been asked twelve ways to Sunday.  However, after re-reading the answer, this is a perfectly good and acceptable answer to a question that is as opinion-based as this once, so I've not only retracted my down-vote, but voted it up.

Comment: @DavidStratton Thanks...I'm *always* open to suggestions :)

Comment: According to the Catholic.com link you gave, which is excellent by the way, it does not affirmatively say whether God *did* or *did not* choose to do it that way. After reading it, I am left with the impression that special creation and theistic evolution are both acceptable to the Catholic church. It made special note to say that the genesis account is surely factual, but it is not chronological, that is to say, that God did "separate the waters" and he did "cause plants to grow" but maybe not in that order. The days are written by grouping topics, which formed and filled the Earth.

Comment: @fredsbend Great point! See my edit...

Answer (score 2):

Your question is based on a twenty four hour day. The 24 hour day is based on the rotation of the Earth in relation to the sun which did not happen until Genesis 1:5:

Gen 1:3 through 5

> 3  And God said, Let there be light: and there was light. 
>   4  And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness. 
>   5  And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and the morning were the first day.

And so verses 1 and 2 even though they may have been 24 hours long since time began at Genesis 1:1. We cannot say with certainty that it was.

What we can say with certainty is that Man was created on the sixth day.

Gen 1:26 through 31

> 26  And God said, Let us make man in our image, after our likeness: and let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth. 
>   27  So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them. 
>   28  And God blessed them, and God said unto them, Be fruitful, and multiply, and replenish the earth, and subdue it: and have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over every living thing that moveth upon the earth. 
>   29  And God said, Behold, I have given you every herb bearing seed, which is upon the face of all the earth, and every tree, in the which is the fruit of a tree yielding seed; to you it shall be for meat. 
>   30  And to every beast of the earth, and to every fowl of the air, and to every thing that creepeth upon the earth, wherein there is life, I have given every green herb for meat: and it was so. 
>   31  And God saw every thing that he had made, and, behold, it was very good. And the evening and the morning were the sixth day.

It is also worth noting that Genesis 1:5 says that the evening and the morning were the first day, however we do not know if the evening began at verse 1 or verse 4.

No one but God can definitively answer your  question.

However if you are interested you might like to watch;

[http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=1KMd-5MVF_E]

Comment: Nice answer. Because they all say it was evening and morning, I believe they were literal 24-hour days. Nevertheless this is a great point of view.

Comment: I don't like this answer for the same reason I didn't initially like Charles Albrook's answer - it presumes to answer from all perspectives, but in reality, there is no consensus.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but I will attempt to clear some doubt here. Most people who take the creation account as historical believe that the Earth is 6000-7000 years old.

From a scientific point of view, you can use half-lives to tell how old things are. However, to have a starting point, assumptions must be made. For example, in physics, you can scientifically tell where a ball is going to land, but you must make some assumptions, about some external factors (that you do not know) that might change the course of the ball, such as air or physical interference. In the same way, assumptions must be made in dating techniques.

Carbon-14 dating, is a technique used to find how old organic material, a living thing, is. For Carbon-14 dating, the assumption that the amount of it has always been constant, which is not necessarily true, must be made. Experiments by Dr. Willard Libby, founder of the Carbon Dating method, found this to be untrue.

What the Bible says stands. The Bible is not there to explain certain scientific experiments that, as revolutionary as they may be, could be based on erroneous assumptions. Time and time again, scientific 'fact' has been proven incorrect, more recently [absolute zero](http://www.nature.com/news/quantum-gas-goes-below-absolute-zero-1.12146). The Bible has never been proved wrong, and it is my firm belief that it never will, for it is the Word of God.

For more information, read these articles:

[Doesn’t Carbon-14 Dating Disprove the Bible?](http://www.answersingenesis.org/articles/nab/does-c14-disprove-the-bible)

[Is Carbon-Dating Accurate?](http://amazingdiscoveries.org/C-deception-carbon_dating_radiometric_decay_rates)

Comment: This answer addresses about 1% of the scientific evidence for an old earth.

Comment: @DJClayworth Is this what was asked? No. Please re-read the question. If there is any other widely used technique for ORGANIC dating, please share.

Comment: No. But plenty of other ways of dating human remains.

Comment: @DJClayworth As stated, If there is any other widely used technique for ORGANIC (human or other living things) dating, please share.

Comment: 2 downvotes... Not sure as to why. Anyone care to explain? Maybe those who downvoted?

Comment: @DJClayworth Surprisingly, I upvoted this. I'm a Bible literalist and I'd buy anything that can provide even the slightest possibility that Carbon-Dating is not accurate.

Comment: @Mawia Please don't vote for opinions you agree with, please vote for answers that provide accurate descriptions of the Christian view(s) on something.

Comment: @DJClayworth brother, you say my answer is not useful, but have provided no reason as to why. Radiocarbon dating seems to me to be the only accepted way of dating organic material. You said there are "plenty of other ways of dating human remains." Please share what these are. Also please describe why this is not an "accurate description of the Christian view" on this topic. Please don't downvote for opinions you simply DON'T agree with but do not have any arguments to back up your opinion. Last time I checked, downvotes are for answers that are not helpful to the topic.

Comment: @DJClayworth This view is also supported by a popular website [GotQuestions.org](http://www.gotquestions.org/radiometric-dating.html). It's not our own opinion.

Comment: You should have avoided answering this question anyway because it is off-topic. You play with fire and you might get burned.